# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute already defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, iis-6

Visual Studio 2012, Entity Framework 6.2, IIS 6.1, C#, MVC

My site compiles and runs in Visual Studio fine. When I try to access the site through IIS, I get this error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Column' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If I view the detailed compiler output, I see the following message:

> CS0433: The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ew_clientdatamanagement_1.0\12dbcac1\bd6265c0\assembly\dl3\eeabf2e6\008fb2c1_bb3cd001\EntityFramework.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'

This is clearly a configuration issue because the site compiles and works in Visual Studio.

I have references to the following in my web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

The EntityFramework.dll file is in the "bin" folder of my web site.  I have verified that the version of EntityFramework.dll is for the .NET 4.0 runtime.

I have tried deleting the Microsoft.NET temporary folder, but that didn't help.

I have also tried removing the web.config reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, but EntityFramework.dll references this assembly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do a search through your project for `Column` and see everywhere you have defined it. are you missing a `runat="server"` for a particular object also have you tried stopping and restarting IIS.. what does the header section of your .aspx page look like as well do you have `CodeBehind = or CodeFile=`

Comment: I am not using .NET server-side controls.  The site runs fine in Visual Studio...but won't compile under IIS.  Same source/bin in both.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the solution and doing a total rebuild also since you have the assembly referenced in the config.. did you also add it manually to the using section at the top of the .cs file..? as well as manually adding the reference to the references node..? edit your tag and add MVC so you can avoid confusion

Comment: This is an MVC application.  I should have mentioned that, but I don't think ASPX or MVC is related to this problem.

Comment: Yes...cleaned, built, restarted IIS, deleted bin/rebuilt, deleted Microsoft.NET temporary cache...same symptom....works in Visual Studio but not in IIS.

Comment: have you proib generate the public folder from vs? verify that all assemblys are in the correct folder, in some issues the location of assembly is just on /bin or /debug or other folder

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll is in the GAC.  I have a reference to that in web.config.  EntityFramework.dll is in the bin folder.

Comment: Again, both assemblies are found and loaded under IIS and, for some reason, the CS0433 (above) only happens under IIS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my website (not webapp) after generating a Code First codeset from our database. EF.dll and EF.SqlServer.dll are both in my Bin directory. I've also tried the Temp file cleanup like you did, to no avail. Did you ever find a solution to this?